# Плагин Yop Poll на вордпресс

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin

Создал голосовалку через плагин Yop Poll, далее шорткодом ставил ее во все записи:

```
  $shorcode_poll='[yop_poll id="3"]';
  print do_shortcode($shorcode_poll);
```

Голосовалка везде однотипная: Да, Нет, но нужно чтобы голоса для каждой страницы подсчитывались отдельно (сейчас проголосовав на одной странице везде столько же голосов), кто-нибудь знает как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Для каждой страницы вам нужно создавать отдельный шорткод, так как получается что на всех страницах вы выводите одну и ту же голосовалку, соответственно и голоса считаются везде.

Comment: Для меня это не подходит, так как страниц очень много, и ежедневно добавляется ещё 50 и более. Ранее переписывали плагин и было как нужно, но видимо после обновления доработки слетели